# R time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, posixct, scales-xml

I have data with stock prices(data). Stock data I would like to visualize it. I first use ggplot R plotting to visualize the series.

```
    Date      Closed
2010-07-19    0.0808
2010-07-20    0.7547
```

When I used below code

```
    my_date_format <- function()
{
  function(x)
  {
    m <- format(x,"%b")
    y <- format(x,"%Y")
    ifelse(duplicated(y),m,paste(m,y))
  }
}

ggplot(data, aes(x=Date, z=Closed)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels=my_date_format())
```

I had an error: Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only

Of course I tried to change Date as a Date format, but it didn't work too.
I also tried

```
    ggplot(data, aes(Date, Closed)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(format = "%Y-%m-%d") + xlab("") + ylab("Closed")

or

ggplot(data,aes(Date,Closed))+geom_line() + scale_x_date(breaks = “1 month”,labels=date_format(“%b/%y”)) +xlab(” “) + ylab(“closed”)
```

but it doesn't work too.
My desired output looks similary like this
[image]

Comment: Changing `scale_x_datetime` to `scale_x_date` solved this error for me. The datatype I used was originally `posixct` changed to `as.Date`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work fine using the argument `date_labels`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
data <- read.table(text= "
Date      Closed
                   2010-07-19    0.0808
                   2010-07-20    0.7547
                   2010-07-21    0.8547", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE)

data$Date <- ymd(data$Date)
ggplot(data, aes(x=Date, y=Closed)) + 
  geom_line() + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%d-%Y")
```

[image]

Regarding you codes, you can't use `scale_x_datetime` if the format of your data is `date` (Assuming that they are). That's why you get the error: `Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only`

Answer (score 6):

If your Date column is a character vector you can convert it using `as.Date`    inside `aes` or previously  `df$date <- as.Date(df$date)` without using additional packages:

```
last_month <- Sys.Date() - 0:29
    df <- data.frame(
      date = last_month,
      price = runif(30)
    )
    df$date <- as.character(df$date)
# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(date), price)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%d-%Y")
```

[image]
**As per your desired format**, inserting a line break between the month and day and year (`\n` inside `date_labels`) and rotating y-axis tick marks `angle = 90` in `theme`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(date), price)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%d-\n%Y")+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]