# Change x-axis names in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am not very good in R, and need some help.

My ggplot has a lot of dates(in the x-axis) so you can't actually see the dates, and I want to change it to months to give a better overview of the plot.

For example to something like this in the link:
[Display the x-axis on ggplot as month only in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596811/display-the-x-axis-on-ggplot-as-month-only-in-r?fbclid=IwAR2MR_NQgff-3Z-T511loTBkc0CxptfTTSW205ACBldJx9LCLy1iPNQjKBY)

This is the script I'm using:

```
r <- read.csv("xxdive.csv", header = T, sep = ";")
names(r) <- c("Date", "Number")
r <- data.frame(r)
r$Date <- factor(r$Date, ordered = T)

r[1:2, ]
Date         Number
16.02.2015   97
17.02.2015   47

library(tidyverse)

ggplot(r, aes(Date, Number)) + 
  theme_light() + 
  ggtitle("16.02.15-10.02.16") + 
  ylab("Dives") + 
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), color = "blue")
```

This shows what kind of data I have.

I have tried using scale etc, but I can't make it work..
I hope this was understandable, and that someone can help me!! :)

Comment: Keep / convert `r$Date` as / to date format and read `?scale_x_date`

Answer (score 1):

I would convert column Date to data type Date

```
r$Date <- as.Date(r$Date, "%d.%m.%Y");
```

instead of converting it to data type factor.

```
r$Date <- factor(r$Date, ordered = T);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky without a working example, but try this.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
r <- read_delim("xxdive.csv", ";", col_types = list(col_date(), col_integer()))
names(r) <- c("Date", "Number")
ggplot(r, aes(Date, Number)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = 1), color = "blue") +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month") +
    ylab("Dives") +     
    ggtitle("16.02.15-10.02.16") + 
    theme_light()
```